# How to do bulk updates using a map?

Tags: apex, map, bulkification

This is a contact trigger handler updating the account. The aim is getting the most common email domain and rolling that up from the contacts to the account. I'm doing this by looping through the accounts, then the contacts at each account and adding all the email domains to a list.

Then I'm looping through that list and adding each string with an integer of 0 to a map, which is nested in another map, "counts", where the account id is being added too. Then in the next loop, I'm incrementing the integer for each string in the map.

Next, with the "maxkey" string, I'm getting the first string in the map and comparing its integer to all the others in the map until it gets the string with the highest integer, the most commonly occurring. I'm putting that into a new map with the account id as the key.

Finally, I'm assigning the value of this map to the account's email domain field, hopefully matching the result to the right account id.

**This works, but not for bulk updates**. If I use dataloader with a batch size of 200, it will update the accounts with the wrong account email domain. I don't understand where I've gone wrong trying to relate the result to the right account?

```java
list<String> lt = new list <String>();
        
for (Account acc: [SELECT Id, Name,Account_Email_Domain__c, 
              (SELECT Id, Accountid, Email_Domain__c FROM Contacts LIMIT 200),
              FROM Account WHERE Id IN 
              (SELECT Accountid FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :newcontact)]){
    Account accObj;
    if (lstAccountsToUpdate.containsKey(acc.Id)) {
        accObj = lstAccountsToUpdate.get(acc.Id);
    } else {
        accObj = new Account(Id = acc.Id);
        lstAccountsToUpdate.put(acc.Id, accObj);
    }

    Map<Id, Map<String,Integer>> counts = new Map<Id, Map<String,Integer>>();
    Map<Id, String> finaldomain = new Map<Id, String>();
                  
    for (Contact co: acc.Contacts) {
        lt.add(co.Email_Domain__c);      
    }

    for (Contact co: acc.Contacts) {
        for(String s1: lt) {
            if(s1 != null){
                if(!counts.containsKey(co.Accountid)){
                    counts.put(co.Accountid, new Map<String, Integer>{s1 => 0});
                }
                if(counts.containsKey(co.Accountid)){
                    counts.get(co.Accountid).put(s1, 0);
                }
            }
        }
       
        for(String s1: lt) {
            if(s1 != null){
                if(!counts.containsKey(co.Accountid)){
                    counts.put(co.Accountid, new Map<String, Integer>{s1 => 0});
                }
                if(counts.containsKey(co.Accountid)){
                     counts.get(co.Accountid).put(s1,counts.get(co.Accountid).get(s1)+1);
                }
            }
        }
        
        String maxKey = counts.isEmpty() ? null : new List<String>(counts.get(co.Accountid).keyset())[0];
        
        for(String s1:counts.get(co.Accountid).keySet()) {
            finaldomain.put(co.Accountid, maxKey = counts.get(co.Accountid).get(s1) > counts.get(co.Accountid).get(maxKey) ?s1 : maxKey);
        }
    }
    
    accObj.Email_Domain__c = finaldomain.get(accObj.Id);
```

Comment: I also don't understand how this question doesn't show research effort or how it's unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use some odd code patterns here, and some poor variable naming makes things harder to read than they should be, but I think that the following is suspicious

```java
for(String s1:counts.get(co.Accountid).keySet()) {
    finaldomain.put(co.Accountid, maxKey = counts.get(co.Accountid).get(s1) > counts.get(co.Accountid).get(maxKey) ?s1 : maxKey);
}
```

Trying to run an equivalent version in anonymous apex

```java
Map<Integer, String> testMap = new Map<Integer, String>();
String tba = 'value1';
testMap.put(1, tba = false ? tba : 'value2');

system.debug(tba);        // prints "value 2"
system.debug(testMap);    // prints "{1=value2}"
```

appears to produce the correct output, but an assignment inside of a call to `.put()` just feels icky.

Best guess at this point is that something about your double loops over `lt` (i.e. the email domains) is causing some funky behavior. It could also be that you never clear out `lt` between accounts.

At any rate, I think you're making your life harder than it needs to be here. The counting here can be done entirely through SOQL by using `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`.

```java
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

// gather data to feed the query
for(Contact cont :newcontact){
    accountIds.add(cont.AccountId);
}

Map<Id, Account> accountsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Account>();

// Grouping first by AccountId helps ensure that you're only counting the number of times
//   an email is used under each account (instead of the other way around)
for(AggregateResult aggResult :[
            SELECT AccountId, Email_Domain__c, COUNT(Id) 
            FROM Contact 
            WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds
            GROUP BY AccountId, Email_Domain__c
            ORDER BY AccountId, COUNT(Id) DESC]){
    Id acctId = (Id)aggResult.get('AccountId');

    // Because of the ORDER BY, the first time we encounter an AccountId will be
    //   the Email domain with the highest count.
    // So if our map already contains the accountId as a key, we can just move on to
    //   the next row
    if(accountsToUpdate.containsKey(acctId)){ 
        continue;
    }

    accountsToUpdate.put(new Account(
        Id = acctId,
        Account_Email_Domain__c = (String)aggResult.get('Email_Domain__c')
    );
}

update accountsToUpdate.values();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help again @Derek F, the aggregate query worked. I'll keep playing with maps though, I really want to understand how to use them properly.